# OpenGL gluProject() - strange results

Tags: opengl, projection

I'm tying to use `gluProject` function, to get point coordinates in 2d window after "rendering". The problem is, that I get strange results. For example: I've got a point with x=16.5. When I use `gluProject` on it I get x= -6200.0.

If I understand `gluProject` OK, I should get a pixel position of that point on my screen after "rendering" - am I right? How can I convert that strange result into on-screen pixel coordinates?

Thank you for any help!

Code I use (by "sum1stolemyname"):

```
GLdouble modelview[16], projection[16]
GLint viewport[4];

glGetDoublev(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, *modelView);
glGetDoublev(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, *projection);
glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT, *viewport);

double tx, ty, tz;

for(i = 0; i < VertexCount; i++)
{
  gluProject(vertices[i].x, vertices[i].y, vertices[i].z, 
    modelview, projection, viewport,
    &tx, &ty, &tz)
}
```

Comment: This won't compile. You are mixing the * and & operators.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah it does unfortunately it does it as far as the far plane so you can construct a 'ray' into the world. It does not give you the actual position of the pixel you are drawing in 3D space. What you can do is make a line from the screen to your point you get from the gluProject then use that to find the intersection point with your geometry to get the point in 3D space. Or another option is to modify your input matrices and viewport so the far plane is a more reasonable distance.

Comment: Ha my bad I am thinking of GLUnProject.